# Why ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json do not get updated in Azure DevOps for Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I need Azure DevOps CI/CD Tips for Azure Data Factory.

I have Azure Data Factory which has Web Activity to Post json to Azure LogicApps. (ADF Web->Logic Apps) I have made URL as parameter in Web Activity.

```
Parameter in ADF Pipeline: MyReport_LogicAppURL
```

I have edited ARM Template
Manage->ARM Template->Edit Parameter Configuration

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "properties": {
      "parameters": {
        "MyPremLoad_OnPremDb": {
          "defaultValue": "="
        },
        "MyReport_LogicAppURL": {
          "defaultValue": "="
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I Save it and then publish.
However I don't see any updates in ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json in Git Repo

Why ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json do not get updated in Azure DevOps for Azure Data Factory? I have successfully done this in other environments. Also other person has successfully deployed MyPremLoad_OnPremDb in past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you have a non-standard git hierarchy, you should find or place the
`arm-template-parameters-definition.json` in `Datafactory` folder or the root folder.

Once you have made changes to parameter definitions, save and refresh the browser to reload the configurations.

If you still don't see the changes, i would suggest deleting `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` from your publish branch manually and `save parameter definitions` > `refresh browser` > `publish` from ADF portal.

Make sure you have a right `json` structure after the edit, Do share if you see any particular errors.

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "MyPremLoad_OnPremDb": {
                "defaultValue": "="
            },
            "MyReport_LogicAppURL": {
                "defaultValue": "="
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json file is located under "my-data-factory" folder in adf-publish branch. There are many parameters set by other persons in past, but not mine latest. I cannot see error in ARM Template structure.

Answer (score 0):

I added default value to parameter and it got fixed. Thank you KarthikBhyresh-MT for your support.